# What is the proper way of using the AWS CLI EC2 "wait" function?

Tags: shell, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-opsworks, aws-cli

I am using AWS opsworks for statically configuring a simple stack, consisting of two layers (Rails app server and mySQL db).

After having successfully configured and started the stack and deploying my app, I would like to automate the start activity for the stack as part of my pipeline. AWS CLI provides the features to start stacks, retrieve the instance id's of the individual servers and then poll AWS for the completion status ("instance-running"), using the EC2 wait command.

The script below is what I am using (the first command starts the stack, the second command retrieves the instance id's for the two hosts, the third initiates the wait command for these two servers):

```
#!/bin/bash

aws opsworks --region us-east-1 start-stack --stack-id 9e1b0534-5b38-4fa5-b30c-f849dda8f46b          

instance_id=$(aws opsworks --region us-east-1 describe-instances --stack-id 9e1b0534-5b38-4fa5-b30c-f849dda8f46b --query "Instances[].Ec2InstanceId" --output text)

aws ec2 wait --region ap-southeast-1 instance-running --instance-ids $instance_id
```

When running this script, I always get a "InvalidInstanceID" exception on one of the two id's even though it is definitely the right ID. Secondly, if running the last command in the shell directly while starting the stack in parallel via the AWS console, it turns out that the wait command returns BEFORE the servers are actually up and running (which is the whole point of the exercise).

Lastly, I couldn't find any information about time outs which seem to be quite essential for a blocking async operation. where can the wait timeout be defined ?

Any idea whether there is a glitch in my code, or some specific consideration that I need to take into account?

Answer (score 0):

The `aws opsworks describe-instances` command is using the `--region us-east-1`, but the `aws ec2 wait` command is using `--region ap-southeast-1`.  Are you sure that your instances you're waiting for are in ap-southeast-1 as opposed to us-east-1?

Comment: Opsworks operations always have to use us-east-1 irrespective of which region the servers are in while EC2 and other foundation services are exposed in every region.